# Error in reversing string

Tags: c

I know this question is extremely common and the solution is well-known. But for a long time, I am getting an error I cannot figure out. I am trying to reverse a string in C. My code is given below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *reverse(char *);

int main(void) {

    char str[] = "Hello";
    char *rev;

    rev = reverse(str);
    printf("The reversed string is %s", rev);
    return 0;
}

char *reverse(char *str){

    char *end = str;
    char tmp;

    if(str){
        while(*end){
            ++end;
        }
        --end;

        while(str < end){

            tmp = *str;
            *str++ = *end;
            *end-- = tmp;



        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

As result, I am getting "leH", not "olleH". Can anyone point out why?

Comment: I would suggest that you step through the code with a debugger and the issue will probably be apparent. (Plus it's a good exercise).

Comment: Why not use a debugger and step through it? You definitely should learn to use the debugger, it's a must for a programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you return the incremented pointer, use another pointer or index notation and it will work, like this

```
char *reverse(char *str)
{
    char *end;
    char  tmp;
    int   i;

    end = str;
    if ((str == NULL) || (*str == '\0'))
        return str;
    while (*end != 0)
        ++end;
    --end;

    i = 0;
    while (str + i < end)
    {
        tmp       =  str[i];
         str[i++] = *end;
        *end--    =  tmp;
    }
    return str;
}
```

When you return `str`, it's no longer pointing at the beginning of the string.

Comment: `if (str == NULL) return NULL;` --> `if (!str || !*str) return str;`

Comment: type of `i` should be `size_t`.  `reverse("");` invokes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The pointer `str` you return in `reverse()` does not point to the beginning of the string, but somewhere in the middle at the end of the loop.

Another problem with your function is in case you pass an empty string: `end` is decremented from the end of the string and points outside the string.  This invokes undefined behaviour.

You should use 2 temporary pointers to perform the task:

```
char *reverse(char *str) {
    if (str && *str) {
        char *p = str;
        char *end = p + strlen(p) - 1;

        while (p < end) {
            char tmp = *p;
            *p++ = *end;
            *end-- = tmp;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Or if you prefer to use index variables:

```
char *reverse(char *str) {
    if (str && *str) {
        for (size_t i = 0, j = strlen(str); i < --j; i++) {
            char tmp = str[i];
            str[i] = str[j];
            str[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of achieving reversing string is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *reverse(const char *);

int main(void){
    char *s = "hello world";
    char *s_rev = reverse(s);
    printf("%s => %s", s, s_rev);
    free(s_rev);
    return 0;
}
char *reverse(const char *s){
    char *s_new = strdup(s);
    char *s_begptr = &s[0];
    char *s_endptr = &s[strlen(s) - 1];
    char *ptr = NULL;
    for (ptr = s_endptr; ptr >= s_begptr; ptr--, s_new++){
        *s_new = *ptr;
    }
    *s_new = '\0';
    s_new -= strlen(s);
    return s_new;
}
```

Notice we are not using any temporary variables to store the value, rather, using both start and end pointers of the same string and using the loop to work backwards from the end of string in reverse.